# Flutter: How to render a popup widget on top globally without loosing interactions with other widgets?

Tags: flutter

I want a widget to go beyond its parent's borders. People recommend using `Stack` with `clipBehavior: Clip.none` (for example, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57871530/flutter-how-to-make-a-child-widget-go-beyond-its-parent) question).

It works, but such a widget is rendered below all the other widgets in the app.

Consider the following code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';

Widget getTestClipNoneWidget(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 300.h,
        color: Colors.black,
        child: Stack(
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: 267.h,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  border: Border.all(
                    width: 1.r,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
                width: 100.w,
                height: 50.h,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        height: 200.h,
        width: 50.w,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

It will produce this (tested in Flutter Web):

[image: The widgets]

The thing is, **I want the green box to be above the blue one**. How do I achieve that? Ideally in all platforms, not only in Flutter Web.

My Flutter setup configuration:

```
Flutter 3.13.7 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 2f708eb839 (8 days ago) • 2023-10-09 09:58:08 -0500
Engine • revision a794cf2681
Tools • Dart 3.1.3 • DevTools 2.25.0
```

EDIT: As I wrote in the comments, I need this to show popup dialogs in Flutter Web. For example, when a user clicks on a search bar and starts typing then search results should appear below the search bar. They should be rendered on top of every other widget. And yes, you can use `showDialog` or something like that but it doesn't allow interacting with other widgets until the dialog is dismissed. It means you cannot continue typing until you close the dialog which is obviously not an acceptable solution. If you know how to make such dialogs in another way (for example, use something instead of `Stack`), I will accept it as the answer as well.

EDIT2: I need a general solution, not only for search bars but for any custom popup widgets.

Comment: you mean instead of `top: 267.h` you want `top: 250.h`?

Comment: No, I mean `top: 267.h` because I want to test whether I can make a widget go beyond its parent's borders while at the same time be rendered on top of other widgets, in this case, the blue box.

Comment: aasah, so those two boxes don't have the same `Stack` parent, then no: green cannot be drawn on top of blue, as green is a child of first column item while blue is the second column item, most likely you need `Overlay` for that

Comment: How do one implements popup dialogs in Web then? For example, when a user clicks on a search bar and starts typing then search results should appear below the search bar. They should be rendered on top of every other widget. And yes, you can use `showDialog` but it doesn't allow interacting with other widgets until the dialog is dismissed. It means you cannot continue typing until you close the dialog which is obviously not an acceptable solution.

Comment: I was planning to implement such dialogs with `Stack` and `clipBehavior: Clip.none` but they are rendered below other widgets like the green box below the blue box.

Comment: @pskink I've tried `Overlay` but didn't manage to make it work. If you know how to make it work then would you please adjust the code with the green and the blue boxes so that the green one is rendered on top?

Comment: check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CompositedTransformTarget-class.html and https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CompositedTransformFollower-class.html, this can help on how to use them: https://medium.flutterdevs.com/compositedtransformfollower-in-flutter-479e7f537db1

Comment: have you tried SearchView in flutter if searching and showing suggestion is your concern?

Comment: @Rahul no, I haven't tried `SearchView` but I need such popup dialogs for other things as well, not only for search bar.

Comment: please look at portal package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_portal

Comment: the easiest way to implement is portal package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a widget for that.

[image: See the screen recording of the code example below]

Try **Autocomplete** widget which works well for the search ui you explained.

> A widget for helping the user make a selection by entering some text and choosing from among a list of options. [more](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Autocomplete-class.html)

For the popup ui, See **Overlay** widget.

> [Overlays](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html) let independent child widgets "float" visual elements on top of other widgets by inserting them into the overlay's stack. The overlay lets each of these widgets manage their participation in the overlay using [OverlayEntry](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/OverlayEntry-class.html) objects.
>
> The Overlay widget uses a custom stack implementation, which is very similar to the Stack widget. The main use case of Overlay is related to navigation and being able to insert widgets on top of the pages in an app. For layout purposes unrelated to navigation, consider using Stack instead.

In the example below. The [OverlayEntry](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/OverlayEntry-class.html) is the widget that is being drawn (The widget that you wanted to popup). It inserted in to the [OverlaySate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/OverlayState-class.html). To anchor the overlay (popup) widget to another, it's wrapped with [CompositedTransformFollower](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CompositedTransformFollower-class.html) and the target widget with CompositedTransformTarget, with LayerLink class linking them. This helps the popup follow along when scrolling.

Note: The overlay method literally overlays the whole app screen. So, it may draw over sticky widgets like the appbar or bottom nav.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

void main() => runApp(const App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Material(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              titleAutoComplete,
              spaceSmall,
              const AutoCompleteExample(),
              spaceMedium,
              textLorem20,
              spaceMedium,
              titleCustomAutoComplete,
              spaceSmall,
              const CustomAutoCompleteExample(),
              spaceMedium,
              textLorem20,
              spaceMedium,
              titleOverlay,
              spaceSmall,
              const OverlayExample(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OverlayExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const OverlayExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<OverlayExample> createState() => _OverlayExampleState();
}

class _OverlayExampleState extends State<OverlayExample> {
  // A place in an [Overlay] that can contain a widget.
  late OverlayEntry overlayEntry;
  // The current state of an [Overlay].
  late OverlayState overlayState;
  // The link object that connects this [CompositedTransformTarget]
  // with one or more [CompositedTransformFollower]s.
  final layerLink = LayerLink();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    overlayEntry = buildOverlay();
    overlayState = Overlay.of(context);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Make sure to remove OverlayEntry when the widget is disposed.
    overlayEntry.remove();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CompositedTransformTarget(
      link: layerLink,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () => overlayState.insert(overlayEntry),
        child: const Text('Click Me'),
      ),
    );
  }

  buildOverlay() => OverlayEntry(builder: (_) {
        return Positioned(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          child: CompositedTransformFollower(
            link: layerLink,
            targetAnchor: Alignment.topCenter,
            followerAnchor: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: const FlutterLogo(),
          ),
        );
      });
}

class AutoCompleteExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const AutoCompleteExample({super.key});

  static const List<String> colors = <String>[
    'red',
    'green',
    'blue',
    'purple',
    'yellow',
    'orange'
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Autocomplete<String>(
      fieldViewBuilder: fieldViewBuilder,
      optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
        if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
          return const Iterable<String>.empty();
        }
        return colors.where((String option) {
          return option.contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
        });
      },
      onSelected: (String selection) {
        debugPrint('You just selected $selection');
      },
    );
  }
}

class CustomAutoCompleteExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomAutoCompleteExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Autocomplete<MapEntry<String, Color>>(
      fieldViewBuilder: fieldViewBuilder,
      optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
        if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
          return const Iterable<MapEntry<String, Color>>.empty();
        }
        return colorsMap.entries.where((MapEntry<String, Color> element) {
          return element.key.contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
        });
      },
      displayStringForOption: (option) {
        return option.key;
      },
      onSelected: (MapEntry<String, Color> selection) {
        debugPrint('You just selected $selection');
      },
      optionsViewBuilder: (context, onSelected, options) {
        return Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          child: Material(
            elevation: 1,
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: options.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                final option = options.elementAt(index);
                return InkWell(
                  onTap: () => onSelected(option),
                  child: Builder(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      final bool highlight =
                          AutocompleteHighlightedOption.of(context) == index;
                      if (highlight) {
                        SchedulerBinding.instance
                            .addPostFrameCallback((Duration timeStamp) {
                          Scrollable.ensureVisible(context, alignment: 0.5);
                        });
                      }
                      return Container(
                        color: highlight ? Theme.of(context).focusColor : null,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: option.value),
                            const SizedBox(width: 24),
                            Text(option.key),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

// Constants and stylings

const spaceSmall = SizedBox(height: 8.0);
const spaceMedium = SizedBox(height: 16.0);

var titleAutoComplete = const Text(
  'AutoComplete Example',
  style: textStyle,
);

var titleCustomAutoComplete = const Text(
  'Custom AutoComplete Example',
  style: textStyle,
);
var titleOverlay = const Text(
  'Overlay Example',
  style: textStyle,
);

const textLorem20 = Text(
    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas fugiat tempore commodi quo quam repellat ipsum blanditiis sapiente at nobis!');

const textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);

const Map<String, Color> colorsMap = {
  'red': Colors.red,
  'green': Colors.green,
  'blue': Colors.blue,
  'purple': Colors.purple,
  'yellow': Colors.yellow,
  'orange': Colors.orange,
};

Widget fieldViewBuilder(
  context,
  textEditingController,
  focusNode,
  onFieldSubmitted,
) {
  return TextFormField(
    controller: textEditingController,
    focusNode: focusNode,
    onEditingComplete: onFieldSubmitted,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: 'Search Color',
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
          8,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

---

### Edit: Simplified step by step

#### Autocomplete

**1.** Declare an array of objects. Strings in this case.

```dart
const colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
```

**2.** Insert the Autocomplete widget into the tree.

```dart
Autocomplete<String>(
      optionsBuilder: (textEditingValue) {
        if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
          return const Iterable.empty();
        }
        return colors.where((option) {
          return option.contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
        });
      },
      onSelected: (selection) {
        debugPrint('You just selected $selection');
      },
    );
```

#### OverlayEntry

Overlay has a state so it needs to be a StatefulWidget.

**1.** Declare the widget you want to popup above other widgets.

```dart
  final myWidget = const FlutterLogo();
```

**2.** Declare OverlayEntry, OverlayState and LayerLink;

```dart
late overlayEntry;
late overlayState;
final layerLink = LayerLink();
```

**3.** Override initState and assign instances

```dart
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    overlayEntry =  overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(builder: (_) {
      return Positioned( // Helps to size the widget
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        child: CompositedTransformFollower( // Anchors & follows the target widget
          link: layerLink, // Links this widget to the target
          targetAnchor: Alignment.topCenter,
          followerAnchor: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          child: myWidget, // Your popup widget
        ),
      );
    });

    overlayState = Overlay.of(context);
  }
```

**4.** Insert the widget you want to anchor you popup to into the tree.
A button in this case and call `overlayState.insert(overlayEntry)` to make it popup.

```dart
CompositedTransformTarget( // Target widget follower is anchored to
      link: layerLink, // Links this widget to the follower.
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () => overlayState.insert(overlayEntry),
        child: const Text('Click Me'),
      ),
    );
```

**5.** To remove

```dart
overlayEntry.remove();
```

Comment: It works, thank you! But does it listen to router updates? Seems like it doesn't. Also what if we need to dismiss this dialog when a user clicks anywhere on the screen (except clicking inside the dialog, of course)?

Comment: Router updates? The OverlayEntry has a builder method, see if you can listen to router updates there. For removing it by clicking outside of it self, Try wrapping your page with a `GestureDetector` and on tap check if it's mounted then remove like so `if (overlayEntry.mounted) overlayEntry.remove();`

Comment: Better to use `Listener` widget because usual `GestureDetector` won't fire if some child is also listening to pointer events. BUT I've tried wrapping my page with `Listener` and it fires when you click on the popup dialog but we shouldn't popup the dialog in this case.

Comment: The bounty question was a search field with live results at the bottom. `Autocomplete` solves it. Aside that, A general solution that covers every use case gets complicated and it's beyond our current issue. `Overlay` is just a suggestion that may be customized to each use case

Comment: Actually I think I know how to do it. You can write `key: <some key>` in the popup widget and then register this key in some singleton service. Then add a `Listener` somewhere on top like in `main.dart`. Then in the `onPointerUp` of that `Listener` check that the pointer was not inbounds of the popup widget by using the registered key to get info about their `RenderBox`.

Comment: Or a focus node that works like how `TextField` looses it's focus when clicked outside of it.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your MaterialApp home with `stack` and manage your popup globally with `riverpod`

Here is full code example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

// Create global Provider
final StateProvider<bool> showDialogProvider = StateProvider((ref) => false);

void main() {
  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: Stack(
        children: [
          const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
          Align(
            alignment: const Alignment(0, 0),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.6),
              height: 150,
              width: 150,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends ConsumerState<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                ref.read(showDialogProvider.notifier).update((state) => true);
              },
              child: const Text('Show Dialog'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it will work but it will need a `Bloc`, singleton or some other service to register and dismiss such dialogs. Also you would need to listen to all the router's navigation updates and all the nav bars updates (if you have nav bars like bottom nav bar) so that when the user opens or closes the current page all dialogs are dismissed. Also listen to click updates on the area outside the dialog and dismiss the dialog in such cases (probably need a `Listener` widget because usual `GestureDetector` won't fire if there some child is also listening to pointer events).

Comment: Apart from that and maybe some other cases which I could have missed it will work. It looks like a very custom solution for such a seemingly general purpose but still. I will accept this answer if nobody writes a better solution until the bounty expires.

Comment: I edited the answer and added riverpod to manage dialog globally

Comment: Also you would need to pass info about the desired position of such popup dialogs if they are not for example centered on the screen. BUT I am not sure how this would work with scrollable lists. I guess you would need to somehow listen to move updates of these lists. Sounds complicated...

Comment: Cabdirashiid's answer seems like it can deal with scrollable lists without too much hustle.

Answer (score 1):

To show your green widget above the blue, you juste have to define it (the green) as last widget in stack's children.

This is how  Stack works the last widget of its children is on top of the others and is therefore displayed last.

```
  Widget getTestClipNoneWidget(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
    children: [
      Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 300.h,
        color: Colors.black,
        child: Stack(
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: 267.h,
              child: Container(
                height: 200.h,
                width: 50.w,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.green,
          border: Border.all(
            width: 1.r,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
        width: 100.w,
        height: 50.h,
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

By the way, if the green zone contains a button or a GestureDetector, you must place it at the end to work correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but there are cases when it is not clear how to use `Stack`. For example, what if I want to create a popup dialog by clicking on an item in a vertical `ListView`? The dialog may intersect the item below the clicked one.

Comment: I don't think Stack is the widget you need 

did you tried Overlay widget ? 
explanation here =>  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhkaDua0rhE .
| How to use stack =>
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1qlgbNN0BaE