# Flutter - Create a search bar with dropdown that doesnt push content down but instead overlays on it

Tags: flutter

I want to create a google type search bar.
Every time user types in something - app will make a API request to backend and show results in a dropdown below the search bar just like google does.
But I have other content under my search bar which gets pushed down everytime dropdown opens up.
If I use Positioned() widget then the dropdown list only occupied the predefined space provided in parent stack widget.

Code I tried:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class X1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const X1({super.key});

  @override
  State<X1> createState() => _X1State();
}

class _X1State extends State<X1> {
  bool visible = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      children: [
        Stack(
          children: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  visible = !visible;
                });
              },
              child: Text('Button'),
            ),
            Positioned.fromRelativeRect(
              rect: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
              child: Visibility(
                child: Container(width: 50, height: 50, color: Colors.pink),
                visible: visible,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Container(width: 50, height: 50, color: Colors.green),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

[image: OnClick - dropdown only occupies same height as button. I would like it to overlay on green container below]
[image: Without click]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Ajax search dropdown that is using flutters inbuilt Autocomplete Widget
- Dropdown wont push content down as it opens up.
- Very usefull in forms/popups where other fields exists along with search box.
- We pass in searchUrl which is used to search the typed value in db by making GET request.

```
class AjaxSearchDropdownFloating extends StatefulWidget {
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final String searchUrl;
  final Map<String, String>? searchUrlParams;
  final Function(Map<String, dynamic>) onSelected;
  final String? initialValue;
  final String label;

  // search url response is going to be a list of dict. dict[displayKey] will be shown in dropdown
  final String displayKey;

  const AjaxSearchDropdownFloating(
      {super.key,
      required this.width,
      this.height = 300,
      required this.searchUrl, // basic url without keyword search. eg: /xyz/recomm/
      this.searchUrlParams,
      required this.onSelected,
      required this.displayKey,
      this.initialValue,
      this.label = 'Search'});

  @override
  State<AjaxSearchDropdownFloating> createState() => _AjaxSearchDropdownFloatingState();
}

class _AjaxSearchDropdownFloatingState extends State<AjaxSearchDropdownFloating> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double mediumFont = 20;
    return SizedBox(
      width: widget.width,
      child: Autocomplete<Map<String, dynamic>>(
        initialValue: TextEditingValue(text: widget.initialValue ?? ''),
        fieldViewBuilder: (
          BuildContext context,
          TextEditingController textEditingController,
          FocusNode focusNode,
          VoidCallback onFieldSubmitted,
        ) {
          return TextField(
            controller: textEditingController,
            focusNode: focusNode,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              label: Text(
                widget.label,
                style: const TextStyle(color: AppColors.appGrey),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        displayStringForOption: (Map<String, dynamic> value) {
          return value[widget.displayKey];
        },

        //Listview widget on how the dropdown will look like
        optionsViewBuilder: (
          BuildContext context,
          AutocompleteOnSelected<Map<String, dynamic>> onSelected,
          Iterable<Map<String, dynamic>> options,
        ) {
          return Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Material(
              elevation: 4,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: widget.width,
                height: widget.height, // Set the desired width
                child: ListView.separated(
                  itemCount: options.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      height: mediumFont * 3,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero, // Set the border radius
                      ),
                      child: TextButton(
                        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                          shape: const BeveledRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
                          ),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          onSelected(options.elementAt(index));
                        },
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Text(
                            options.elementAt(index)[widget.displayKey],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return const Divider();
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        // Return options Map<String,dynamic> to show in dropdown list
        optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) async {
          List<Map<String, dynamic>> searchList = []; // Map<String, dynamic>

          // TODO write your custom get request here
          http.Response? resp = await BaseApi().getHttp(
            api: widget.searchUrl,
            authenticatedReq: true,
            queryParams: {'search': textEditingValue.text, ...?widget.searchUrlParams},
          );

          if (resp.statusCode == 200) {
            final respBody = jsonDecode(resp.body); //list

            // if resp is paginated then get results key
            if (respBody is Map && respBody.containsKey('results')) {
              searchList = respBody['results'];
            } else if (respBody is List<dynamic>) {
              // convert list<dynamic> to list<map<dynamic,dynamic>>
              for (Map<String, dynamic> dict in respBody) {
                searchList.add(dict);
              }
            }
          }

          return searchList;
        },
        onSelected: (Map<String, dynamic> selection) {
          widget.onSelected(selection);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `Autocomplete` widget. The following code should give you something like this

[image]

The data class

```dart
class Airline {
  final String name;
  final String country;
  final String founded;
  Airline({
    required this.name,
    required this.country,
    required this.founded,
  });

  factory Airline.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Airline(
      name: map['name'] as String,
      country: map['country'] as String,
      founded: map['founded'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

The api call function

```dart
 Future<List<Airline>> apiSearch(String query) async {
    String baseUrl = 'https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/airlines?search=';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(baseUrl + query));
    final List<dynamic> list = jsonDecode(response.body);
    return list.map((e) => Airline.fromMap(e)).toList();
  }
```

The Autocomplete widget. A debouncing method before calling the api here, might be ideal to avoid calling on each keystroke.

```dart
Autocomplete<String>(
  optionsBuilder: (textEditingValue) async {
    if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
      return const Iterable.empty();
    }
    // Important: This runs on each keystroke, maybe debounce
    final result = await apiSearch(textEditingValue.text);
    return result.map((e) => e.name);
  },
  onSelected: (selection) {
    debugPrint('You just selected $selection');
  },
)
```

For more examples and how the results are customizable, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77341797/22785194)